# Server Specifications for Web Application

Tags: mysql, php, aws

I am trying to select the configuration for a web application built in PHP 5.5 and MySQL 5.1. I will also be deploying PHPmyAdmin for the MySQL database. Both the web application and the database will be in the same server. I am also contemplating on the options to use AWS or Azure.

My gripe is that I am unsure of the specifications for the RAM required and the number of CPU cores for the web application.

Typically, optimally, it should be able to cater for 300 simultaneous connections but I surmise that at any one time, it will be about 50% or less number of users accessing the system.

I hope to get some advise from the community here. Thanks.

Comment: And your question is? Did you attempt any performance tests of your application?

Comment: Sorry, but this is too broad for Q&A. The answer would depend on the web architecture (OPA, traditional), how complex the server-side processing will be, how much data will be pushed around, what caching is in place, how big the DB's working set will be and the complexity of queries. Try stress testing on an existing box, see how many TPS you get and what saturates first, then go from there.  Voting to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your web application build on PHP 5.5 and MySQL 5.1, having 150-200 concurrent connection,you should plan at least following configuration.

[i] RAM - Start with 2 GB and upscale if performance is low.

[ii]vCPU - Start with 03 vCPU core

[iii] HDD - SSD

RAM/vCPU is upgradeable anytime with 10 minutes of downtime. It is always trade off between performance v/s price, but resources only is not criteria. You need to verify your soft code time-to-time and database optimization by index update, statistics update, rebuild index etc. as well.

Comment: hi @BavishiPN, can you advise where to look for the best practices for software code and database optimization? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may read this guide http://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/performance/